# Linq-to-SQL entites unstanding? please help?

Tags: wcf, linq-to-sql, orm, observablecollection

I’m having a little bit of difficulty understanding some architectural principles when developing a service. If you make a call to a WCF service and it returns a collection of items(Orders) (which are custom made classes made up From  LINQ-to-SQL  entity data) to a client and each item has a collection of items(OrderItems) (one-to-many) that are also made up from the same LINQ-to-SQL context. If I make another call to the service and request a particular OrderItem and modify its details on the client side, how then does the first collection of Items realise that one of its Orders OrderItem has changed from the client side. I am taking the approach of when changing the OrderItem I send the OrderItem object to the WCF service for storage via LINQ-to-SQL commands but to update the collection that the client first called I use IList interface to search and replace each instance of the OrderItem. Also subscribing each item to the PropertyChanged event give some control. This does work with certain obvious limitations but how would one 'more correctly' approach this by perhaps managing all of the data changing from the service itself.. ORM? static classes? If this is too difficult question to answer, perhaps some link or even chat group that I can discuss this as I understand that this site is geared for quick Q/A type topics rather than guided tutorial discussions.

Thanks all the same.

Chris Leach

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple clients changing the same data at the same time, at the end of the day you system must implement some sort of [Concurrency Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control). Broadly thats going to fall into one of two categories: pessimistic or optimistic.

In your case it sounds like you are venturing down the optimistic route, whereby anyone can access the resource via the service - it does not get locked or accessed exclusively. What that means is ultimately you need to detect and resolve conflicts that will arise when one client changes the data before another.

The second architectural requirement you seem to be describing is some way to synchronize changes between clients. This is a very difficult problem. One way is to build some sort of publish/subscribe system whereby, after a client retrieves some resources from the service, it also subscribes to get updates to changes to resource. You can do this either in a push or pull based fashion (pull is probably simpler, i.e. just poll for changes).

Fundamentally you are trying to solve a reasonably complex problem, but its also one which pops up quite frequently in software.